# how to update the url after saving a post

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm building an editor which can save and update post. The problem I'm facing is that after saving the post for the first time, I get a snippetId from the server which I want to show in the url immediately or else my route is still `http://localhost:8000/editor` and if I hit save button again then it saves a duplicate copy with a different id. I want the editor url to be something like `http://localhost:8000/editor/123` after saving for the first time so that when I hit the save button again then it updates the post instead of saving a duplicate copy with a different id. I was wondering how to tackle this problem? can someone help me find a solution for this problem

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-hooks-3bvg8)

editor.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { savePost, retrievePost } from "./actions/posts";

class Editor extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      title: "",
      enteredText: ""
    };
    this.commonChange = this.commonChange.bind(this);
  }
  commonChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    //Load the snippet
    retrievePost(this.props.match.params.snippetId);
  }

  // Save Snippet
  performSave = snippets => {
    console.log("save function clicked");
    const { enteredText, title } = this.state;
    this.props.savePost({
      snippetId: this.props.match.params.snippetId, //if the url doesn't change then this also doesn't change so I get duplicate copies 
      snippetDescription: enteredText,
      snippetTitle: title
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="titletext"
          placeholder="Enter title here"
          limit-to="64"
          className="inptxt"
          name="title"
          onChange={this.commonChange}
        />
        <button className="btn savebtn" onClick={this.performSave}>
          Save Snippet
          <i className="fas fa-save" />
        </button>

        <textarea name="enteredText" onChange={this.commonChange} />
      </>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  snippets: state.snippets
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { savePost, retrievePost }
)(Editor);
```

action.js

```
import { SAVE_POST, UPDATE_POST, RETRIEVE_POST, HOME_LOADED } from "./types";
import axios from "axios";
export const savePost = ({
  snippetId,
  snippetDescription,
  snippetTitle
}) => async dispatch => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  };

  let snippetData = {
    title: snippetTitle,
    snippetDescription: snippetDescription
  };
  // --------------------------------------
  console.log("in savePost action");
  try {
    if (snippetId == null) {
      const res = await axios.post("/api/savesnippets", snippetData, config);
      snippetData.snippetId = res.data; //cause I only get snippetId from the server
      dispatch({
        type: SAVE_POST,
        payload: snippetData
      });
    } else {
      //add snippetId here for update use only --------------------------------------
      await axios.post(
        "/api/update",
        JSON.stringify({ ...snippetData, snippetId }),
        config
      );
      // --------------------------------------
      dispatch({
        type: UPDATE_POST,
        payload: snippetData
      });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `history.push()` from react-router for this purpose like:

```
history.push('/editor' + id_you_get_from_ajax_call);
```

And use it where you are getting the ajax response, so for every success you will get a new `id_you_get_from_ajax_call` and it will update the route.

and create a matching route for `editor` like:

```
<Route path="editor/:id" component={ YOUR_COMPONENT } />
```

[React-router history.push() Reference](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter)

Comment: should I add `history.push('/editor' + id_you_get_from_ajax_call);` in the actions file after the api call? also I was wondering if componentDidUpdate could also help with this or not?

Comment: yeah I get that history.push will redirect me. but where will I add this line? in the posts.js file in the actions folder?

Comment: You have to put this code under the event handling function and use `history.push()` with the updated state. That means under `performSave` function

Comment: how do I access the `id_you_get_from_ajax_call` in the editor component in the performSave function because we get the id in the action.js file. can you please help me? I couldn't figure out how to do it. can you show me in the codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-hooks-3bvg8

Comment: You can get the server response in action and you will send that response to reducer, and that updated state is available in `mapStateToProps`

Comment: yeah I know that. But it won't be immediately available I believe. will it be received in the componentDidUpdate lifecycle method or without any function directly to `mapStateToProps`? If so, then I should do `snippet.snippetId` in the `performSave` instead of 'this.props.match.params.snippetId` since I'll be receiving the snippetId from `mapStateToProps`. could you show me how to go on about with this?